# Continuity equation in quantum mechanics - Verification Sakurai 2.7.30

Tags: quantum-mechanics, vector-fields, complex-numbers

I am trying to verify Equation 2.7.30 from Sakurai's "Modern Quantum Mechanics" 2ed. The bottom line of my question is:

$?? \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*}=0 ?? $

And here is how I arrived at it. Below, all equations straight from Sakurai have (==) and all of my intermediate equaitons just have (=)

$$\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot \vec{j}==0 \ \ $$

$$\rho=={\left| \psi \right|}^2 ,\ \ \ \ \ \vec{j}==\frac{\hbar}{m}Im\left( \psi^{*}\nabla\psi \right)-\frac{e}{mc}\vec{A}\left| \psi \right| ^2==\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left( \psi\nabla\psi^{*}-\psi^{*}\nabla\psi \right)-\frac{e}{mc}\vec{A}\left| \psi \right| ^2 $$

$$\frac{1}{2m}\left[ -i\hbar\nabla-\frac{e}{c}\vec{A} \right]\cdot\left[ -i\hbar\nabla-\frac{e}{c}\vec{A} \right]\psi+e\Phi\psi==i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=\frac{1}{2m}\left[ -\hbar^2\nabla^2+\frac{i\hbar e}{c}\left( \nabla\cdot\vec{A}+\vec{A}\cdot\nabla \right)+\frac{e^2}{c^2}A^2 \right]\psi+e\Phi\psi $$

$$ \frac{\partial\rho}{\partial t}=\psi\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi^{*}+\psi^{*}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi =\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left( \psi^{*}\nabla^2\psi-\psi\nabla^2\psi^{*}\right)+\frac{e}{mc}\nabla\cdot\vec{A}\left|\psi\right|^2+\frac{e}{2mc}\left( \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*}  \right)$$

$$ \nabla\cdot\vec{j}=\frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left( -\psi^{*}\nabla^2\psi+\psi\nabla^2\psi^{*} \right)-\frac{e}{mc}\nabla\cdot\vec{A}\left|\psi\right|^2-\frac{e}{mc}\left( \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*} \right) $$

In the last two equations, I have lined things up so it is easy enough to see that everything cancels except $ \frac{e}{2mc}\left( \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*} \right)-\frac{e}{mc}\left( \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*} \right) $

Which can be remedied if

$?? \psi^{*}\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi^{*}=0 ?? $

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be a factor of 2 in the equation $d\rho /dt=...$ since $ \nabla (\bar{A} \psi) + \bar{A} \nabla\psi = 2 \bar{A} \nabla \psi $ since we can impose $\nabla \bar{A}=0$. Hope it can be helpful :)

Comment: I am not sure about Div(A) being zero (and I want to make sure we mean Div(A) instead of Grad(A) ). Though Div(B)=Div(Curl(A))=0, I do not recall seeing any such special property of (A). Another "check" on this is that a different QM author, Shankar, shows Div(A) in equation 4.3.7 in their book, without mentioning that Div(A)=0. Also, careful of the order of operations; we definitely have ( Div(A) ) φ and not Div(Aφ); this can also be seen in equation 4.3.7 in Shankar (Though note that Shankar is using P=-i hbar Grad -> P∙ = -i hbar Div).

Comment: Sorry, I meant $div(\bar{A})$. Physics is Gauge invariant and you can impose the Coulomb Gauge: $div(\bar{A})=0$. In Shankar 4.3.7 it is not said that we have $(div(A)) \phi$, it only defines H operator as  H=---+$\frac{ie\ hbar}{mc}\bar{A}\nabla$+---. For more explicit calculations, I recommend you Greiner's book "Quantum Mechanics. An introduction". In particular, you can check Chapter 9 where everything is overdetailed.

Comment: You are most definitely on to something with the Coulomb Gauge condition, where Div(A) indeed is zero. I will have to start again with that in mind, before tangling myself up. I still think that by defining the (H) operator as $...+\frac{i e \hbar}{mc} \nabla\cdot\vec{A}+...$, the $\nabla\cdot\vec(A)$ operation happens before multiplicitavely operating on $\psi$.

Comment: @elscan This is where the problem occurs. Why do you think $\nabla \cdot(\vec A)$ operation happens before multiplicitavely operating on $\Psi$? Didn't we always do operations form right to left?

Comment: @RicknJerry, (H) is ["wrapped up"] in parenthesis so we have $(...+\nabla\cdot\vec{A}+...)$ acting on a scalar. There would need to be some property which said $( \nabla\cdot\vec{A})\psi=\nabla\cdot(\vec{A}\psi)$ but this is not general since $\nabla\cdot(\vec{A}\psi)=\vec{A}\cdot\nabla\psi+\psi\nabla\cdot\vec{A}$. If $\nabla$ , A and psi were matrices then right-to-left would be in the order of precedence, but not before parenthesis. (AB)C=A(BC) is a special property. I have now seen the book mentioned by Lox where Greiner said right away Div(A)=0. I must redo the process shown in my question